# Which techniques are used by SageMaker Neo for model optimizations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker-compilers

Does SageMaker Neo (SageMaker compilation job) use any techniques for model optimization? Are there any compression techniques used (distillation, quantization etc) to reduce the model size?

I found some description here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/neo.html) regarding quantization but it's not clear how it could be used.

Thanks very much for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo is optimizing inference using compilation, which is different and often orthogonal to compression

- **compilation** makes inference faster and lighter by specializing the prediction application, notably: (1) changing the environment in which the model runs, in particular replacing training frameworks by the least amount of necessary math libraries, (2) optimizing the model graph to be prediction-only and grouping together operators that can be, (3) specializing the runtime to use best the specific hardware and instructions available on a given target machine. Compilation is not supposed to change the model math, thereby doesn't change its footprint on disk
- **compression** makes inference faster by removing model weights or making them smaller (quantization). Weights can be removed by pruning (dropping weights that do not influence much results or distillation (training a small model to mimic a big model).

At the time of this writing, SageMaker Neo is a managed compilation service. That being said, compilation and compression can be combined, and you can prune or distill your network before feeding it to Neo.

SageMaker Neo covers a large grid of hardware targets and model architectures, and consequently leverages numerous backends and optimizations. Neo internals are publicly documented in many places:

- According to [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/unlock-performance-gains-with-xgboost-amazon-sagemaker-neo-and-serverless-artillery/), Neo uses [**Treelite**](https://treelite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for tree models optimization ([*Treelite: toolbox for decision tree deployment*](https://mlsys.org/Conferences/doc/2018/196.pdf), Cho et Li)
- According to its [landing page](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/neo/), Neo uses [**Apache TVM**](https://tvm.apache.org/) too. TVM is the leading open-source compiler, developed by [Tianqi Chen](https://tqchen.com/) and the [DMLC](https://github.com/dmlc) community (that also co-authored [XGBoost](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02754) and [MXNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01274)). TVM tricks are abundantly documented in [*TVM: An Automated End-to-End Optimizing Compiler for Deep Learning*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.04799.pdf) (Chen et al)
- According to [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-neo-makes-it-easier-to-get-faster-inference-for-more-ml-models-with-nvidia-tensorrt/), Neo also sometimes leverages [**NVIDIA TensorRT**](https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt), the official inference optimization stack from NVIDIA
- Neo also uses a number of Amazon-developed optimization:

  - [*A Unified Optimization Approach for CNN Model Inference on Integrated GPUs*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.02154.pdf) (Wang et al): *"Our work is already deployed
    in Amazon SageMaker Neo Service"*
  - [*Optimizing CNN Model Inference on CPUs*](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/atc19-liu-yizhi.pdf) (Liu et al)*"NeoCPU is used in Amazon SageMaker Neo Service"*